# Generate all combinations of length 2 using 3 letters

Tags: r

The simplest way to generate such combinations would be to use `combn` function as follows:

```
print(combn(letters[1:3],2))
```

The output that it generates is:

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "a"  "a"  "b" 
[2,] "b"  "c"  "c"
```

This doesn't generate combinations like `aa`, `bb` (same character repeated).
This even doesn't generate `ba` if `ab` is generated.

I want to generate all such combinations of length 2 for a vector [a,b,c].

Is there a simple way to do so in R?

Comment: Use `expand.grid` i.e. `expand.grid(rep(list(letters[1:3]), 2))`

Comment: ... though be aware of the default `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`

Comment: Here's an alternative (which, unsurprisingly, is less elegant than the suggestion by @akrun ) `unique(t(combn(rep(letters[1:3],2),2)))`

Answer (score 2):

The `paste0` function is vectorized and so succeeds with outer:

```
outer(c('a','b','c'), c('a','b','c'), paste0)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "aa" "ab" "ac"
[2,] "ba" "bb" "bc"
[3,] "ca" "cb" "cc"
```