# "non-numeric argument to binary operator" in ggmap

Tags: r, ggmap

## This question has been updated several times.

This is a further question from [how to create data frames (not just one) at once in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53625126/how-to-create-data-frames-not-just-one-at-once-in-r/53626313#53626313). I really can't understand the error message. I have two data frames:

```
> route1
                      X1                         X2                         X3
1 Balboa Park, san diego, ca    Coronado, san diego, ca  USS Midway, san diego, ca
2 Balboa Park, san diego, ca  USS Midway, san diego, ca    Coronado, san diego, ca
3    Coronado, san diego, ca Balboa Park, san diego, ca  USS Midway, san diego, ca
4    Coronado, san diego, ca  USS Midway, san diego, ca Balboa Park, san diego, ca
5  USS Midway, san diego, ca Balboa Park, san diego, ca    Coronado, san diego, ca
6  USS Midway, san diego, ca    Coronado, san diego, ca Balboa Park, san diego, ca
```

and

```
> place
# A tibble: 8 x 5
  name                                                hour type  short                abbr  
* <chr>                                              <dbl> <chr> <chr>                <chr> 
1 Balboa Park, san diego, ca                             4 place Balboa Park          bal   
2 USS Midway, san diego, ca                              2 place USS Midway           midway
3 Coronado, san diego, ca                                4 place Coronado             coro  
4 Cabrillo National Monument, san diego, ca              2 place Cabrillo             cab   
5 La Jolla Cove, san diego, ca                           2 place La Jolla             ljc   
6 4002 Wallace St, San Diego, CA 92110                   4 place Old Town             ot    
7 Hotel Republic San Diego, Autograph Collection        NA hotel Autograph Collection NA    
8 THE US GRANT, a Luxury Collection Hotel, San Diego    NA hotel Luxury Collection    NA
```

My idea is using `ggmap` package to get driving time from `Hotel Republic San Diego, Autograph Collection` (`place$name[7]`) to the first place in `route1`'s first row, then get driving time from the first place in `route1`'s first row to the second place in `route1`'s first row, and so on, until from the last place in `route1`'s first row to `THE US GRANT, a Luxury Collection Hotel, San Diego`(`place$name[8]`). Sum up the time, store in `route1$time` column. Then do the same thing for the following rows. So my code is

```
library(ggmap)
register_google(key = "my_google_key_here")
route1$time <- 0
for (i in 1:length(route1)) {
  for (j in 1:length(route1[i,])) {
    if(j == 1){
      route1$time[i] <- route1$time[i] + mapdist(from = place$name[7], to = as.character(route1[i,][1]))$seconds
    }
    if(j == length(route1[i,])){
        route1$time[i] <- route1$time[i] + mapdist(from = as.character(route1[i,][j]), to = place$name[8])$seconds
        route1$time[i] <- route1$time[i] + mapdist(from = as.character(route1[i,][j - 1]), to = as.character(route1[i,][j]))$seconds
    }
    for (j in 2:length(route1[i,]-1)) {
      route1$time[i] <- route1$time[i] + mapdist(from = as.character(route1[i,][j - 1]), to = as.character(route1[i,][j]))$seconds
    }
  }
}
```

Executing this code gives me

```
Error in FUN(left, right) : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

error message, I think it is saying that I add a character to a number, but I can't find it.

Comment: Do you know why your error message says `time + mapdist(from = place$name[7], to = as.character(route1[i,` but the code you posted says `time[i] + mapdist(from = place$name[7], to = as.character(route1[i,`?

Comment: @Erin Thank you for bringing it up. I edited my code and updated the question.

Comment: `route1[[i,]]` should be `route1[i,]`

Comment: I don't see it.

Comment: @Erin I see it. But now I have new error.

Comment: Yeah, it would be better to do a tidy version of this. With for-loops and indices, it's really easy to make little mistakes.

Comment: @Erin I did try other script; at the end I felt loop is the best solution. `route1` is extracted from a list, it contains more data frames with different dimensions.

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you're saying now. There are different numbers of columns, and you're doing this computation across the row. Is that correct?

Comment: @Erin Exactly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# this is a nice library for R
library(tidyverse)

# name your variables
# (you can use these as arguments to a function or something)
start = place$name[7]
end = place$name[8]

# wrap your computation into a function which takes
# a row of a data frame as input    
compute_route_time = function(row) {
  # get a vector of stops that you can loop through
  stops = unlist(row)

  # distance from start to first stop
  time = mapdist(from = start, to = stops[1])$seconds
  # iterate through the rest of the route
  n_stops = length(stops)
  for (i in 1:(n_stops-1)) {
    time = time + mapdist(from = stops[i], to = stops[i+1])$seconds
  }
  # finish rout
  time = time + mapdist(from = stops[n_stops], to = end)$seconds

  # collect row as a data frame to preserve old columns
  row = as.data.frame(row)
  # add time column
  row$time = time
  return(row)
}

route1 %>%
  dplyr::rowwise() %>%
  dplyr::do(compute_route_time(.))
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. However there is an error for the last pipe `Error in stop[1] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`

Comment: yep. typo. sorry, just a sec

Comment: I used `stop` instead of `stops` at some point. lol. might work now

Comment: It works now. Thank you so much! But I noticed all routes have the same time 12523. Is it supposed to be? None the less, thank you again.

Comment: Well, the grouping is fine for me, it doesn't just return the same thing. I think you're on your own from here since I don't have `mapdist`. ;) Good luck!

Comment: Hey Erin, this project is done with your help. I wrote a blog post for this object. https://vincent507.wordpress.com/2018/12/09/practice-what-ive-learned-a-plan-for-trip-of-san-diego/

Comment: Aww, that's so, so sweet! Thank you for the credit! :D